# How to do Reverse geocoding using AgmMap?

Tags: angular6, reverse-geocoding

How to do Reverse geocoding using AgmMaps?
Getting Street Address using  latitude and longitude?
what should be imported and what should be the function code??

**appmodule.ts**

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';  
imports: [  
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
   apiKey: 'apikey',
}),
]
```

**app.Component.css**

```
agm-map {
height: 600px;
}
```

**app.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
      title = 'app';
      ngOnInit() {
       }
       latitude = 3.3333;
        longitude = 7.7777;

      *// Reverse geocoding function here*
       }
```

**app.Component.html**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
  </agm-map>
```